# Creating per user calendar in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, calendar

I want to create an application in which every 2-3 users share a calendar between them (some of them might not have a Google account). The application is the calendar owner, and the user can not change the calendar directly.

The documentation of GAE leads to Google Apps calendar which does not seem to fit, since:
1. Creating the calendar on the user account - the user is the owner of the calendar and has full control.
2. Creating multiple calendars on the application's internal Google account - there's a quota that limits the number of calendars created in a 'short time'.

Do I have to implement a calendar from scratch or is there another option?

Comment: You don't say how many calendars you want to create, or what your time constraints are. Google's quotas are very generous in the aggregate, but don't like sustained activity. So you can probably create 20-30 at a rate of one very 3-4 seconds without tripping over any quota limits. If you need more, wait a while (perhaps even a day) and then create some more. It may even take several days, but presumably you only do this once?

Answer (score 0):

You have to roll your own. Google provides the calendar for free under a TOS that prevent abuse. The quotas are enforced to prevent it. I think its reasonable.